# Get hash in <a> link in Javascript

Tags: javascript, substring, href

I try to get an hash to put filter on my page, I work in JS vanilla only, actually i can't find how getting it.. It must be simple but i can't find on internet and I'm newbie..
If someone can help me, it can be a huge move for me, thank's a lot !

```js
function lien(obj) {
  alert(obj.href.hash);
}
```

```html
<a href="#portrait" onclick="lien(this)" class="filters" value="portrait">#portrait</a>
```

Comment: Does it have to be hash? `class="filters portrait"` is a little less of a kludge method. Normally you add the `#` to `href` to ensure that a link field doesnt reload the page.

Answer (score 2):

[The `href` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement)…

> Is a USVString that is the result of parsing the href HTML attribute relative to the document, containing a valid URL of a linked resource.

Strings don't have `hash` properties. You want to read `hash` directly on the link element itself.

```js
function lien(obj) {
  alert(obj.hash);
}
```

```html
<a href="#portrait" onclick="lien(this)" class="filters" value="portrait">#portrait</a>
```

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, thanks à lot !